# Simulate Particle System within Unity UI

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to display particle system within Unity UI elements. I have created particle system within Canvas component but it didn't get visible on actual game screen.

Please check below image:
[image]
I hope you understand my actual point. How can I create Particle System that we can use within Unity Canvas?

Comment: Particles aren't UI objects. In order to have them show up, you'd need to use a world space canvas. Which might cause other issues.

Answer (score 0):

A world space canvas works. Not ideal, but it works, or you can set sortingOrder

ParticleSystemRenderer.sortingOrder / sortingLayerID, Canvas.overrideSorting / sortingOrder / sortingLayerID

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do that is using Render Textures. This way you can render 3D objects into a texture and use it in your ui system. To do this:

1. Create a new layer, for example "GUI3D".
2. In your MainCamera>Culling Mask unselect this new layer
3. Create a new Camera, which Culling Mask only has "GUI3D" enabled. Set its Clear Flags to Solid Color and an alpha 0.
   [image]
4. Create in some folder a new Render Texture
5. In your Camera>Render Texture select the created texture
6. In your Canvas, create a Raw Image and select your created texture
   [image]
7. There are some particle shaders that dont work in Render Textures (https://answers.unity.com/questions/560815/particles-not-showing-up-using-render-texture.html)

Comment: I will practically check this and reply back to you...As I become free, first I will do this task.